# ethminer failed to submit hashrate

Tags: ethereum

Just installed geth and ethminer. On first trial, I got this error. Any idea?

```
ethminer -G -F http://yolo.ethclassic.faith:9999/0x<my-wallet> --farm-recheck 200

[OPENCL]:Found suitable OpenCL device [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] with 6440894464 bytes of GPU memory
miner  13:41:58.403|ethminer  Getting work package...
  ✘  13:42:08.408|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  13:42:08.408|ethminer  Dynamic exception type:        jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out

JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
```

I have geth 1.5.9, ethminer 1.2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pool you are linking with the `-F` flag seems not to exist anymore.

```
 0 ✓ user@ursae ~ $ curl -s -I yolo.ethclassic.faith | head -1
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 0 ✓ user@ursae ~ $ curl -s -I ethclassic.faith | head -1
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

You could try one of the following pools for Ethereum Classic:

- http://www.ethteam.com/
- https://www.epool.io/

Comment: Tried both pools. Got error : Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32603 : INTERNAL_ERROR: : <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: My command : ethminer -G -F http://www.ethteam.com/0x<my-wallet> --farm-recheck 200